# Syntax Error: Unexpected token Else

Tags: javascript, identifier

I am learning Javascript via Codecademy and no have been stumped on this little piece here.

I have supposed to write an if else statement.

It shows me here in the following that there is a Syntac Error with a missing identifier:

```
var userAnswer = prompt("Are you feeling lucky, punk?");

if (userAnswer === "yes");
{

    console.log("Batman hits you very hard. It's Batman and you're you! Of course Batman wins!");
}

 else {

    console.log("You did not say yes to feeling lucky. Good choice! You are a winner in the game of not getting beaten up by Batman.");
}
```

What is wrong with that.... There is no error in this example here:

```
if (age < 18)

{

    console.log("We take no actions or responsibility. Play at your own risk!");
}

else

{

    console.log("Enjoy the game");
}
```

Comment: It would be easier to debug, if you'd use [recommended code conventions](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html) for JS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (userAnswer === "yes");
```

Remove the semicolon.

Comment: And why so? Why can I not have one? Is it like ending the statement?

Comment: with `;` you are telling the script to stop rendering the rest of the statement conditions.  It's because `if()`, it must have condition which therefore starts at `{ }`.  If `if()` doesn't see the condition statement, it stops rendering.

Answer (score 3):

There's a semi-colon after the first conditional check. Also, you should always put the opening bracket of the conditional branch on the same line as the brackets

Answer (score 0):

```
var age;
age = prompt('How old are you?');
if (age < 18)

{

alert("We take no actions or responsibility. Play at your own risk!");
}

else if(age > 18)

{

alert("Enjoy the game");
}
```

Comment: Good answers should include an explanation of code instead of simply just code.

Answer (score 0):

remove the semicolon after

if (userAnswer === "yes");

if you put the semicolon there, you are telling the script to stop there and not to render the next conditional statement that is "else"[SyntaxError: Unexpected token else]

[image: 1]